# UITabBar width not increasing with screen size

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I am implementing a `UITabBar` within another `UITabBar`. My problem is that, the Second TabBar width remains constant regardless of the screen size. This stands out a lot in the bigger screens. I'm attaching a screenshot to make you understand better. Selection is indicated using a blue background
[image: First TabBar on Top Second on the bottom]

[image: Second Tab in Second TabBar Selected]

[image: Third tab Selected in Second TabBar Controller]

Here's the code:

```
GRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tabBar.frame.size.width/2, self.tabBar.frame.size.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context,
                                   [[UIColor colorWithRed:102.0/255.0 green:197.0/255.0 blue:234.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor]);

    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    self.tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = img;
```

The screenshots from iPhone6 Plus

[image: Second Tab Of First TabBar selected(not part of the question, just to show the full picture)]

Comment: Is this default UITabBar? How you highlite buttons?

Comment: Just added the code for that

Comment: How is your autolayout set up?

Comment: Autolayout is set up "normally"..the width of the view is equal to the width of screen.........only the width of the Second Tab, stays at "320"
Whats more interesting is that, if i print the width in the console (self.tabbar.frame.size.width), it shows 375, for iphone 6 and 414 for iphone 6+..but the size does not change in view

Comment: Try to invoke this method(where you set up the width of tab bar) with some delay

Comment: @pkc456 no that did not help either

Comment: How did you implement a UITabBar WITHIN another UITabBar? As far as I know, a UITabBar has always a height of 49, and can contain only objects of class UITabBarItem.

Comment: @ReinhardMänner I have two TabBarControllers-Tab Main Controller and Second Tab Bar Controller. The first Item of Tab Main Controller was connected to a Navigation Controller that is connected to the next TabBarController(Second Tab Bar Controller). Bot their heights are 49, but I set the frames in such a way that the Second Tab Bar Controller comes UNDER Tab Main Controller

Answer (score 5):

Thank you for snippet of a highlight buttons.

Did you want something like this?

Portrait orientation:

[image]

Landscape orientation:


[image]

Code of my ViewController:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITabBar *tabBar;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITabBar *topTabBar;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName :  [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {

    [self highlightTabBarItems:self.tabBar];
    [self highlightTabBarItems:self.topTabBar];
}

- (void)highlightTabBarItems:(UITabBar*)currentTabBar {

    CGFloat highlightedWidth = self.view.frame.size.width/currentTabBar.items.count;
    [currentTabBar setItemWidth:highlightedWidth];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, highlightedWidth, currentTabBar.frame.size.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor colorWithRed:102.0/255.0 green:197.0/255.0 blue:234.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    currentTabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = img;
}

@end
```

Comment: Not for landscape orientation. the app is only meant to run in portrait mode. I want the width to increase with the screensize

Comment: So method viewDidLayoutSubviews probably no need. Please mark answer as right if it helped you.

Comment: it did not help.sorry